# Google Sheets modal dialog is clearing html after form submission (code is at the bottom)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, iframe

#### Goal

I'm trying to execute a piece of code in a Google Spreadsheets modal dialog after pressing a submit button in a form. After the submit button is pressed, I want the dialog to display a loading wheel (I've already made that), then close itself using `google.script.host.close()` after a 1.5 second delay (using `setTimeout()` for that one).

#### Previous Attempt

I was able to get it working before without the submit button and without the `<form>` element, and instead using onclick attributes on normal buttons, but I wasn't able to have the validation work properly with that solution.

#### Outcome

What ended up happening was immediately after pressing the submit button, the contents of the modal dialog disappeared and it just stayed open until I had to close it manually, and none of the code that I wanted to be executed was executed. When I used the Inspector to look at the source html for the dialog, the block was completely empty. All that was left was this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I tried doing the classic debugging solution of `console.log()`. I put a pair of log functions in the submission event handler, one before and one after the `e.preventDefault()`. Neither were logged. I can only assume that this means the function wasn't being executed at all.

#### Desired Solution

I need help identifying what went wrong, or if this is some kind of bug with Google's platform, and how I can improve or fix this (if at all).

#### Edit 1

I have attempted to use `event.preventDefault()`, as has been suggested by the answers given in the linked posts (I have edited the snippet to show how I have attempted to use it). This has not worked, and results in the same outcome described above. (Also elaborated what happened in the outcome).

#### Code Snippets

The snippets following are (in order) **JavaScript**, **CSS**, and **HTML**.

```js
var x;
let ID = t => document.getElementById(t);
var loader = ID('loader');
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  loader.style.visibility = 'visible';
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(res => {
      x = res.arr[1];
      google.script.run.callLibraryFunction('CharacterSheetCode.clearClassEdit');
      switch (res.arr[0]) {
        case 'edit':
          ID('class').value = res.arr[2].class;
          ID('subclass').value = res.arr[2].subclass;
          ID('level').value = res.arr[2].level;
          ID('hitdie').value = res.arr[2].hitdie;
          ID('spellcasting').value = res.arr[2].spells;
          makeEditable();
          break;
        case 'add':
          makeEditable();
          break;
      }

      function makeEditable() {
        ID('class').readOnly = false;
        ID('subclass').readOnly = false;
        ID('level').readOnly = false;
        ID('level').max = (20 - res.lvl) + (res.arr[2] ? Number(res.arr[2].level) : 0);
        ID('hitdie').readOnly = false;
        ID('spellcasting').readOnly = false;
        ID('addedit').disabled = false;
        ID('remove').disabled = false;
        loader.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    })
    .callLibraryFunction("CharacterSheetCode.getClassInfo");
});

ID("form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  loader.style.visibility = 'visible';
  var className = ID('class').value,
    subclass = ID('subclass').value,
    level = ID('level').value,
    hitdie = ID('hitdie').value,
    spells = ID('spellcasting').value;
  if (hitdie % 2 == 0 && hitdie >= 6 && hitdie <= 12) {
    setTimeout(() => google.script.host.close(), 1500);
    google.script.run.callLibraryFunction("CharacterSheetCode.addEditInfo", [className.trim(), subclass.trim(), level, hitdie, spells, x]);
  } else {
    alert(`Error: You must use a d6, d8, d10, or d12 as a hit die. A d${hitdie} will not be accepted.`);
    loader.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

function removeClass() {
  loader.style.visibility = 'visible';
  setTimeout(() => google.script.host.close(), 1500);
  google.script.run.callLibraryFunction("CharacterSheetCode.addEditInfo", ['', '', '', '', '', x]);
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 15px;
}

select {
  border-radius: 1em;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 15px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 1em;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 15px;
}

button:active {
  filter: brightness(80%);
}

.loader {
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #3498db;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader" class="loader" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div id="container" class="container">
  <form id="form">
    <label for="class">Class</label>
    <input type="text" id="class" required readonly="readonly"><br>
    <label for="subclass">Subclass</label>
    <input type="text" id="subclass" readonly="readonly"><br>
    <label for="level">Level</label>
    <input type="number" id="level" style="width: 50px;" min="1" max="20" required readonly="readonly" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
    <label for="hitdie">Hit Die: d</label>
    <input type="number" id="hitdie" style="width: 50px" min="6" max="12" step="2" required readonly="readonly" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"><br>
    <label for="spellcasting">Spellcasting:</label>
    <select id="spellcasting" readonly="readonly">
      <option>None</option>
      <option>Full</option>
      <option>Half</option>
      <option>Third</option>
      <option>Pact</option>
    </select><br>
    <button id="addedit" type="submit" disabled>Add/Edit</button><br>
    <button id="remove" onclick="removeClass()" disabled>Remove Class</button>
    <div>Note: The process of updating the sheet can sometimes take up to 20-40 seconds.</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If the linked duplicate answers doesn't answer your question, [edit] your question to explain how the answers don't satisfy your question. If you're having trouble implementing a solution in the duplicate or don't understand a solution provided, ask a new specific question with the part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Kindly ask a new question for new problems. The original problem of blank page resolved using the duplicates. Right?

Comment: @TheMaster No, I'm still getting the blank page despite integrating `event.preventDefault()`. There were no new problems, I'm just elaborating on some background details that happened after the original problems were occurring.

Comment: Did you redeploy it?

Comment: You should also put `ID("form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault(...` inside the window load event handler

Comment: @BenCraven Try removing the `type="submit"` from the button, that is the problem most of the time for me.